# template.Execute() vs. template.ExecuteTemplate()

Tags: go, go-templates

The following code generated error:

```
panic: template: body: "body" is an incomplete or empty template
```

```
//go:embed resources/*
var res embed.FS

func main() {
    root, _ := fs.Sub(res, "resources")
    t, err := template.New("body").ParseFS(root, "home.html")
    assert(err)
    assert(t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil))
}
```

the template file `resources/home.html` is very simple:

```
{{define "body"}}
Hello World!
{{end}}
```

If I change the last line of main() to `t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "body", nil)`, the problem is gone.

From the library source code, I noticed that the error is because of:

```
func (t *Template) execute(wr io.Writer, data interface{}) (err error) {
    ... ...
    if t.Tree == nil || t.Root == nil {
        state.errorf("%q is an incomplete or empty template", t.Name())
    }
    ... ...
}
```

But **why** `t.Tree` or `t.Root` is `nil`?  My go version is:

```
go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64
```

Comment: *"except of course the whole program struture may differ a bit."* -- did the *base names* of the template files change? Did the previous project have a file named `body` which was then renamed in the new project to something else, for example `body.html`? e.g. https://go.dev/play/p/AyUSOtyZZSP

Comment: no, their is no file named body or body.html etc. the path of the template is `templates/login.html` and `templates/home.html` (in both projects).  The most notable structure difference is that the old project has multiple packages (i.e. code in different sub folder, while the new does not.

Comment: If the file names and relative locations didn't change then the code must have changed, either the Go code, or the template code. If you still want to claim that the code didn't change then you'll need to provide some proof, i.e. a [mcve], otherwise there is nothing in the question that supports your claim that two identical versions of the same code behave differently.

Comment: I understand, but it may not be easy to provide a minimal reproducible example.  Alternatively, I try to understand where and when is t.Root and t.Tree set, and try to trace why it is not set.

Comment: If you have `template.New("body")` it will be executable with `Execute` if one of the parsed files has a matching base name, as I've already explained, *or*, if one of the parsed files defines a `body` template with the `{{ define "body" }}` action. (compare this: https://go.dev/play/p/s8Drl946Hxr to the example in the first comment)

Comment: @mkopriva I managed to reproduce the problem with a very simple program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.  VSCode automatcally import `text/template` for me.  This package will not properly parse `{{define "..."}}` directive.

Use `html/template` worked OK.